# how to install cutout animation tools

Tags: add-on

I've been trying to install the Cutout Animation Tools (COA Tools) addon I downloaded on GitHub. This is actually the first addon I'm trying to install on Blender and I just failed multiple times...

I followed the instructions which are : "Download or Clone the github repository to your local drive. If you download the ZIP File from Github, please make sure to unzip. Don't try to install the downloaded zip file directly in blender. This won't work. Once unzipped follow the installation instructions below".

In this unzipped folder there are actually different files :

[image]

In the Blender folder there is a folder named coa_tools, and inside of it we can find this :

[image]

So there are 4 .py files here and 18 more in the folder operators.

From there I go to File -> User Preferences -> Add-ons and click the “Install from file...” button (as instructed), and I select all the .py files and click on "Install from file...".

When it comes back to my User preferences window, nothing happened (I am in the category "User", which contain nothing since this the first addon I'm trying to install).

I also tried to place the folder coa_tools or the different .py files directly in : **/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.78/scripts/addons**

And still nothing. Did I do something wrong or am I missing something?

Hope you can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: could you please add a link to where you got those files and instructions?

Comment: Are you unable to install other add-ons too? Are you using macOS Sierra? If the answer to both of those is "yes", Gatekeeper could be causing the problem. Read more here: https://developer.blender.org/T49473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your download in the root there is a README.md this contains install instructions:

"### Blender Addon:
Zip the coa_folder.
Go to File -> User Preferences -> Add-ons and click the “Install from file...” button.
This will install and enable the Addon for Blender. Don’t forget to save the user preferences, otherwise the addon will not be activated after restart."

as it says go inside the blender folder and zip the coa_tools folder.

then install from file and select that zip folder.

Comment: I was finally able to install the addon, thanks to your explanation. I was my mistake. I misanderstood the part "zip the coa_folder". Following your instructions, I easily installed it! Thanks!